# ActiveRecord Rescue from View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rescue

I build a little e-commerce solution.  At the end of an order, I want the cart to delete, so a user can't access the same cart after ordering.  After I render the order_confirmation page, I have an after_action [:show] that deletes the cart.  If refreshed, the order confirmation page won't work because the line items(items teh user bought) were destroyed with the cart.

This is fine, I already sent them an email and if they refresh the confirmation page I'd like an activerecord::recordnotfound rescue.

my view looks like this though

```
         <% @order.items.each do |id| %>
         <% @line_item = LineItem.find(id) %>
         (line item data to show)
```

When refreshed, the line_items delete and I get an activerecord error.

```
Couldn't find LineItem with id=8
```

Since this is being called from the view, and isn't exactly conventional -- how can I rescue to redirect and say something like "Your Cart is Reset" or something along those lines? I tried putting it in the controller but it didn't get touched (or didn't trigger..)

```
after_action :remove_cart, only: [:show]
 def index
  @orders = Order.all
 end

 def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @cart = current_cart
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
          logger.error "User Refresh Page"
          redirect_to products_path
        raise
 end
```

If it's super advised not to have a loop like that in the view, should create an array in the controller and then loop through them on the view and create the rescue in the controller?

UPDATE:

remove_cart method is pretty blunt, looks like this.

```
def remove_cart
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.destroy
end
```

**Update**

I've followed Damien's instructions but the after commit

gives me this

```
   (6.2ms)  COMMIT
   undefined method `true=' for #<Cart:0x00000106b9fb98>
   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orders/8
   Completed 302 Found in 1933ms (ActiveRecord: 19.4ms)
```

with order.rb

```
 after_commit :archive_cart, on: :create
 private

 def archive_cart
   cart.archive!
 end
```

and cart.rb as

```
def archive!
  update_attribute(active, false)
end
```

Comment: What does your `remove_cart` method look like?

Comment: @line_items aren't specific to this cart.  the (@)order.items are...  Do you mean has_many :line)items, through: :products? I don't have an :items model

Comment: Apologies, I'll read through your question again and give you some suggestions.

Comment: Could you show relevant code for your `Order` model? That shows how `Order.items` is queried without an `Item` model.

Comment: items is a column in the Order model -- I suppose an association would be better. I could set up @order.line_items

Comment: That's... irregular. Your `items` column contains an array of `LineItem` ids? That's one of the reasons you're running into this problem. You should have a join table, using a HABTM or `has_many through` relationship.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55591/discussion-between-peege151-and-damien-roche).

Comment: Don't *actually* remove the cart.

Simply add an attribute that indicates whether the cart is still "open".

Comment: @meagar I agree. If you don't do that, at least have a function to archive the details of the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on our running conversation, here:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55591/discussion-between-peege151-and-damien-roche

---

#### 1. Update your `Order` model to include:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :cart
  has_many :line_items, through: :cart
end
```

Then, in your view:

```
<% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
```

---

#### 2. As `meager` noted, you should archive order details. Add a status to your cart, such as:

```
add_column :carts, :active, :boolean, default: true
```

Then, instead of `@cart = current_cart` in your controller, refer to the `cart` directly via `@order.cart`.

---

#### 3. Move destroy/archive_cart logic into your models

Note: this is not normal behaviour -- `Order` would usually have a `status`, and the `cart` would be archived when that `Order` is confirmed, but asker is using a preliminary model (`OrderPreview`), where each new `Order` is pre-confirmed.

```
class Order
  after_commit :archive_cart, on: :create

  private

  def archive_cart
    cart.archive!
  end
end

class Cart
  def archive!
    update_attribute(:active, false)
  end
end
```

Comment: maybe a postgresql thing but default: 1 not allowed for boolean, so I used true. and then update status may need to do false if 0 doesn't work.

Comment: @Peege151 That's right, `boolean` values I think include "`t`" and "`f`" for PostgreSQL. Which means `status` won't be self-explanatory. Maybe use `active` instead?

Comment: @Peege151 That means you can query model like `cart.active?` instead of, confusingly, `cart.status?` Or, go the other way and use `archived`, then `cart.archived?`

Comment: updated question, after_commit seems not to be working... (sorry I'm not as easy to help as others!)

Comment: @Peege151 might be better to keep errors based on my answer here in the comments, then I can update.

Comment: @Peege151 in `update_attribute`, `active` should be symbol: `update_attribute(:active, false)`

Comment: I thought I had tried that.. let me see -- doh. Ok, thanks - that worked I think I had done active: false.

Comment: @Peege151 great to hear!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I've posted a new question now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212410/new-cart-after-order-completes :)