# New Cart after Order Completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ecommerce solution where when an order is completed, I would like the user to be able to go to cart and see that it is empty.  Previously I destroyed the cart, but that isn't advised so as per some recommendations I added a column to cart that is

```
:active, :boolean, :default true
```

My cart controller looks like this

```
def show 
  @cart = Cart.find_by_id(session[:cart_id])
end

# GET /carts/new
def new
  @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    @cart
    redirect_to @cart
end
```

I have a method in my application controller that looks like this for creating carts.

```
  def current_cart 
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
```

after an order goes through, I have the :active column change from true to false.  How could I make it so that if the current_cart.active? is false, it creates a new cart?

I've tried

```
   def current_cart 
     if Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).active? ==false
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
     end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
```

but I seemed to have two carts working at a time..

**Update**

Tried

```
    def current_cart 
     if Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).active? ==false
      reset_session
     else
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    end
```

No avail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you tried does not return a `Cart` object if the one returned by `Cart.find` is not active - it returns the `cart.id`. The simplest fix would be to return the created cart (like you do in the `rescue` clause):

```
def current_cart 
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  unless cart.active?
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  end
  cart
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

You should also DRY it up - to something like:

```
def current_cart 
  begin
    cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = nil
  end
  unless cart && cart.active?
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  end
  cart
end
```

---

If you don't want to actually *create* a cart in the new scenario, use `new` instead of `create`:

```
def current_cart 
  cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  unless cart.active?
    cart = Cart.new
  end
  cart
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

Comment: the goal here is that after I complete an order and go back to cart, it should say your cart is empty.  My cart is persisting with this code.

Comment: I'm having an unknown problem, not sure how to figure it out.  Your code should work, it doesn't... maybe it would be best to delete the session associated iwth the user and cart... on order completion.. is it bad practice to delete session data? I have tons in a DB already.

Comment: @Peege151 - wouldn't it be simpler to check if the Cart is active in the _view_? Simply _show_ an empty cart if it is not active...

Comment: It should be, I'm not sure why it's not working.  I confirm that the cart is NOT active in the view (order already took place) but it shows the same cart.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Peege151 - my suggestion is simply to _ignore_ the cart if it is not active - draw the page as if there is no cart...

Comment: Sometimes the obvious thing to do is so far away.  Thanks, this works -- as when a user adds items to a cart it creates a new one from here.